# Set canvas shapes size as percentage of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've seen a couple of questions on here that are asking how to set the size of the canvas relative to the window it's in:

1. [Resize HTML5 canvas to fit window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/resize-html5-canvas-to-fit-window)
2. [Relatively sizing HTML Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169879/relatively-sizing-html-canvas#7170097)

What I wanna know is if I can set shapes (i.e. `rect`) inside the canvas relative to the size. For example:

```
canvas.style.width = 100;
canvas.style.height = 30;

canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, "100%", "80%");
```

I have tried setting the `rect` in pixels with the same size as the canvas thinking it would still be relative to the window but didn't turn out that way.
Instead, if I set `canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 30);`, it would be relative to the canvas.

**EDIT:**

Realised my error and stupidity here. When trying to set the `width` of the rectangle to the canvas width, I was using `canvas.style.width` and not 'canvas.width`. I seemed to have forgotten basic HTML for a second...

Comment: Surely you could use: `canvas.height * 0.8` as 80%

Comment: @DBS yes, I have figured out my mistake. Look at my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What prevents you from simply accessing the canvas width on draw?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 30;


function draw(color) {
  canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.heigh);
  canvasContext.fillStyle = color;
  canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height * 0.5);
}
draw("#FF0000");

setTimeout(function() {
  canvas.height *= 2;
  draw("#00FF00");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  canvas.height *= 2;
  draw("#0000FF");
}, 2000);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```