# Setting the height of a canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have the following HTML snippet, which I want to style with CSS:

```
<div class="outer">
  <canvas class=left"></canvas>
  <div class="right">
    <p>First line</p>
    <p>Second line</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is something like on this picture:

[image]

Putting the canvas and div  to the left and right is fine, the problematic part is the sizing of the "left" canvas (red in the picture). Its height should be the same as the height of "right" and it should be always rectangular, i.e. its width should be the same is its height. If possible I would like to do it without setting it to be an exact size, so it will be resized if "right" has different number of lines. Is it possible to achieve it with a pure CSS solution?

Comment: You should try modifying the width-height element of canvas and padding/margin of it.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to make the height *and* width scale in proportion using pure CSS. You could make it auto-adjust height and/or width based on its container size, but JavaScript must be used to achieve the **proportional** scaling you've described.

This answer has some more info on dynamic sized `canvas`: [Relatively sizing HTML Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169879/relatively-sizing-html-canvas)

The other thing to keep in mind is that `canvas` is a *bitmap* technology, not vector. This means that while limited dynamic functionality is possible (as above), in general `canvas` expects to be working in explicit hard-set pixel values.